# Open new window for Action Listener class for a JButton click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

In my ActionListener class I have my if statements prompting the user to enter a string. When I try to execute the program, nothing happens. Before I added the JButton, the spelling game would appear in a small window and text could be entered, and a message displayed whether the correct spelling was given.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class spelling extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button1;

    public spelling() {
        super("Question 1");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        button1 = new JButton("Spelling game");
        add(button1);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            String answer1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("recipracate, reciprocate, reciprokate");
            if (answer1.equals("reciprocate")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "recriprocate is the correct answer"); 
            }
            else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "is the wrong answer"); 
            }

                String answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("quintessence, quintessance, qwintessence");

            if (answer2.equals("quintessence")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "quintessence is the correct answer");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame2, "That is the wrong answer");
            }
        }
    }
}


import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class spellingmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        spelling test = new spelling();
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setSize(300, 150);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine and runs correctly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complete example raises several issues that merit consideration going forward:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- To avoid a `NullPointerException`, a common practice is to invoke the `equals()` method on the constant, which is known to be non-null.

  ```
  "reciprocate".equals(answer1)
  ```
- Make your error dialog easier to read by including relevant text.

  ```
  answer1 + " is the wrong answer"
  ```
- Don't extend `JFrame` unless you are adding new functionality.
- Don't open a new frame [needlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice); you can use the existing `frame`; a message dialog may have a `parentComponent`, but one is not required.
- Test your program by clicking <kbd>Cancel</kbd> on a question to see the result. Consider how you intend to handle this.

Code as tested:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Spelling extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button1;

    public Spelling() {
        super("Questionss");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        button1 = new JButton("Spelling game");
        add(button1);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String answer1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("recipracate, reciprocate, reciprokate");
            if ("reciprocate".equals(answer1)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "recriprocate is the correct answer"); 
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer1 + " is the wrong answer"); 
            }

            String answer2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("quintessence, quintessance, qwintessence");
            if ("quintessence".equals(answer2)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "quintessence is the correct answer");
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, answer2 + " is the wrong answer");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Spelling test = new Spelling();
            test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            test.pack();
            test.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```